# for a function $f:A→B$ with $\left|A\right|<\left|B\right|$ is there any possibility not to be injective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if we have two sets like $A$ and $B$ with cardinality $\left|A\right|<\left|B\right|$ and assume a function $f:A→B$ is there any possibility for $f$ not to be injective?
Because I assumed $A=[1,2,3]$ and $B=[1,2,3,4]$ and a $f=[(1,1),(2,2),(3,2)]$ and $\left|A\right|=3$ , $\left|B\right|=4$ and still $\left|A\right|<\left|B\right|$ but the function is not injective...

Comment: Yes that is correct. Take $f(x)=1$ for each $x$.

Comment: TBH, I want it for Schröder–Bernstein theorem, in this theorem we say $\left|A\right|\le\left|B\right|$ and we are "sure" that the function $f:A→B$ is injective, but in my problem I have a case which is like the situation is theorem ,but it's not injective.

Comment: You don't *need* `\left` and `\right` everywhere. Those are useful when you want to ensure the height of your delimiters matches the height of the text. But if you don't have subscripts or superscripts, it's just clutter. Even with, inline text sometimes benefits from *not* having `\left\right` adjustments which make inconsistent line heights and may cause the text to look a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@black rose

From wikipedia I found this statement of the theorem,

> In set theory, the Schröder–Bernstein theorem states that, if there exist injective functions $f : A → B$ and $g : B → A$ between the sets $A$ and $B$, then there exists a bijective function $h : A → B$. In terms of the cardinality of the two sets, this means that if $|A| ≤ |B|$ and $|B| ≤ |A|$, then $|A| = |B|$.

Is this the one you're talking about?

If yes, it states that IF $f$ is injective THEN $|A| ≤ |B|$ and not vice versa.

Comment: I understand the statement used in Wikipedia but it's been said in Hungerford's algebra that if we have two sets A and B such that|A|≤|B| and |B|≤|A|, then |B|=|A| , and it says that based on the statement there is a function f:A→B and g:B→A which are injective, here we have a different statement from what we have in Wikipedia and I'm totally confused.I think a function f:A→B is injective if |A|≤|B| but it's not necessary for every |A|≤|B| to be injective

Comment: It is true that if $|A| \le |B|$ then **there exist** an injective function $f$ from $A$ to $B$. But not every function from $A$ to $B$ will be injective

Comment: and can I say  $f:A→B$ is injective if $∀a=b\ ∈A⇒f\left(a\right)=f\left(b\right)$ or in other way $∀f\left(a\right)=f\left(b\right)∈B⇒a=b$?

Comment: To prove that $f$ is injective: Let $a$, $b \in A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ and now you prove that $a=b$ and this would give you that $f$ is injective. Or another way to prove the injectivity is to use the nagation of the above statement, i.e. Let $a, b \in A$ such that $a \not = b$ and prove that $$f(a) \ne f(b)$$ Summing it all up, if $f$ is injective then you have that this statement true $$f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$$

Comment: and why it's "⟹" and not "⇔"?

Comment: It is indeed $\iff$. Since $f$ is a "function" or a mapping, then you have $$a=b \implies f(a)=f(b)$$ Now the injectivity of $f$ gives you that $$f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$$ So you'll get $$f(a)=f(b) \iff a=b$$ But in the previous comment I wrote it $\implies$ because we were focusing on the injectivity part.